# Mapping from any matrix of N*N to Circulant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

is it possible to find a function that map $(i,j)$-th entry of any square matrix $M$ to the $(f(i),f(j))$-th entry of a corresponding higher dimensional circulant matrix $\hat{M}$? The dimension of $\hat{M}$ can be arbitrary.

Thank you!

Comment: We can just map the $(i,j)th$ entry to the $[n(i-1) + j + 1]$th diagonal of an $N^2 \times N^2$ matrix, where the $1$st diagonal is the main diagonal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the mapping I want need to be of the form (i,j) -> (f(i), f(j)). This answer is not of such form.

Comment: well, if I understood your question correctly, such a function is impossible.  If we want to make a matrix $M$ into a circulant matrix of a larger size, then we would presumably be using one entry in $M$ to make multiple entries in $\hat M$.  So, the function you describe would take one input to multiple outputs.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, the value of (i,j)-th entry of $M$ will have multiple copies in $\hat{M}$, but I only care whether there is a such function at least maps to one of them.

Comment: ah, no problem then. Now I see the issue.